# How to add a border to a single videoclip

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I just started to use blender because Camtasia is crashing like ***** al the time and Techsmith doesn't seem to care.
I have a few thing tackled like adding text, resizing and i can make things move in and out by using keyframes.

The one thing i cant find any info on is borders, **how can i add a border to a single videoclip?**
With an image overlay i could emulate this but the problem is that i want the border on a single video clip, the video clip in question is rotated and moving around the screen by using keyframes.

In Camtasia you can just enable a border choose a thickness like 6px and choose a color, this wil add a 4sided border to the videoclip/picture.

I am thinking of 2 (untested) solutions richt now but they are time consuming.

- Create a new scene, add the videoclip, add an image overlay (border) and add the scene to the mainscene.
- Create a new project, add the videoclip, add an image overlay (border) render the project and import the rendered videoclip in the mainproject.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender can do all of those things but it takes a little bit of extra effort to set up. There is no "outline" tool, so you make it with a mask.

1. Create a mask in the UV/Image editor (render a frame from the video as a guide f-12), make sure that it is 'reversed' by clicking the Invert Mask button in the mask properties panel

[image: Invert Mask]

2. Shift - A Add a "Color" effect strip above the video you want to highlight and apply a strip modifier in it's Strip Properties panel N key. Set the color strip's "Blend" type to Alpha Over or Over Drop.

[image: color effect strip with mask]

3. To move them around the screen, (1) select both strips and combine them as a Metastrip ctrl-G. (2) Select the metastrip and add a Transform effect strip Shift-A. Select this new effect strip and change its "Blend" type to Alpha over or Over Drop the image or video (3) placed at the bottom of your stack. Use the properties panel to move and keyframe any animation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i was still doing some research and in several ocasions i saw people use masks for different things so i wondered if i could use that. Thanks you very much for the answer and the comprehensive guide.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit more stupid solution respect the other one.
Note: Im working on a resolution of 1920x1080 so I try to make with that proportions. The border wiil have a tickness of 20 pixel.

I add 4 color effect strip somewhere in the time line to work only on these.
Set in N panel Blend: Alpha Under to see the image under (at least in my case)
Each one will be one of the border (top,left,right,bottom)

To do the LEFT one, select one of the color strip, open N panel, enable Image Offset e Image Crop. Then In crop set left 1900 (or horizontal image size - border tick). In image offset in this case X 0, Y 0.

To do the RIGTH one, select another one of the color strip, open N panel, enable Image Offset e Image Crop. Then In crop set left 1900 (or horizontal image size - border tick). In image offset in this case X 1900 (or horizontal image size - border tick), Y 0. In this way the border will be moved on the right side.

To do the BOTTOM one, select another one of the color strip, open N panel, enable Image Offset e Image Crop. Then In crop set botton 1060 (or vertical image size - border tick). In image offset in this case X 0, Y 0.

To do the TOP one, select another one of the color strip, open N panel, enable Image Offset e Image Crop. Then In crop set botton 1060 (or vertical image size - border tick). In image offset in this case Y 1060 (or vertical image size - border tick), X 0. In this way the border will be moved on the top side.

Then select all these 4 strips and group it with CNTRL-G to create a Meta-strip let say "border".

Then If you need it like me to border something like image o video that change position or scale add on this metastrip a Effect strip Trasform with Blend: Cross and then Gruop with CNTRL-G with the "border" metastrip.

In this way un create another Metastrip with inside trasform and "border".
Then if you want to change parameters of each metastrip select it and press Tab.
To change "border" when you press TAB on the first metastrip than you have to select "border" and press TAB again.